# Can not schedule a batch file to run at startup

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a batch file to run at start up.
Here is my command:

```
schtasks /create /tn test /tr c:\simple.bat /sc onstart
```

simple.bat only writes the current time to a file:

```
time /t > now.txt
```

The task is created without issues, I see it when listing tasks via schtasks (it has status ready) and in the Task Scheduler Library in windows.

When running the batch file manually, everything is fine. However, when restarting, I see the batch is not running (no output file with the updated time) and when looking at the output of schtasks I see the status has changed to "Could not start":

```
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status         
======================================== ====================== ===============
test                                     N/A                    Could not start
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe missing security context? [How can I script schtasks so it doesn't need a password?](http://serverfault.com/questions/43539/how-can-i-script-schtasks-so-it-doesnt-need-a-password)

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason you need to use the task scheduler instead of the startup folder?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows 7? I had a similar problem with a script that worked fine if launched from the command line, but that would not run on schedule. The answer, in my case, was very trivial: there was a box to be ticked valid, at the bottom of the window, where you could specify that the task schedule was active or not. May this simply be the case for your too?

---

Please Check the Properties of a given task, then look for the "triggers" tab and make sure that the tick box at the bottom of the "triggers" window is enabled. Sorry I cannot post pictures yet.

Comment: I'm using win7. can you please specify the location of that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this bat file to exe,and then you can schedule it :)
This is a freeware software called [Advanced Bat to exe](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) that can convert bat file to a exe :)